# What to do with multiple invulnerable saves?

Tags: warhammer-40k

My friend has built a dire avenger exarch with a shimmer shield which gives it a 5+ invulnerable save. However it has the ability Battle fortune which gives the exarch a 4+ invulnerable save.

How does this work? Is the shimmer shield just a waste on the exarch?

Comment: The shimmershield gives all the other dire avengers the invulnerable save, it isn't totally redundant.

Answer (score 4):

(Note: I am assuming you are playing 9th edition here since it is the latest ruleset)

The Shimmer Shield is definitely redundant on the Exarch.

From [the rules](https://warhammer40000.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/ENG_40K9_Basic_Rules.pdf) (page 19 under Invulnerable Saves):

> If a model has more than one invulnerable save, it can only use one of them – choose which it will use.

So the player would never have a reason to choose the Shimmer Shield unless the player (for some reason) wanted the Exarch to have a higher chance of dying.